# Get aspect ratio of a monitor

Tags: c#, winforms, aspect-ratio

I want to get aspect ratio of a monitor as two digits : width and height. For example 4 and 3, 5 and 4, 16 and 9.

I wrote some code for that task. Maybe it is any easier way to do that ? For example, some library function =\

```
/// <summary>
/// Aspect ratio.
/// </summary>
public struct AspectRatio
{
    int _height;
    /// <summary>
    /// Height.
    /// </summary>
    public int Height
    {
        get
        {
            return _height;
        }
    }

    int _width;
    /// <summary>
    /// Width.
    /// </summary>
    public int Width
    {
        get
        {
            return _width;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ctor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="height">Height of aspect ratio.</param>
    /// <param name="width">Width of aspect ratio.</param>
    public AspectRatio(int height, int width)
    {
        _height = height;
        _width = width;
    }
}



public sealed class Aux
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get aspect ratio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Aspect ratio.</returns>
    public static AspectRatio GetAspectRatio()
    {
        int deskHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        int deskWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;

        int gcd = GCD(deskWidth, deskHeight);

        return new AspectRatio(deskHeight / gcd, deskWidth / gcd);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Greatest Common Denominator (GCD). Euclidean algorithm. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">Width.</param>
    /// <param name="b">Height.</param>
    /// <returns>GCD.</returns>
    static int GCD(int a, int b)
    {
        return b == 0 ? a : GCD(b, a % b);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use [`Screen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen_members.aspx) class to get the height/width.
2. Divide to get the [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)
3. Calculate the ratio.

See following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int nGCD = GetGreatestCommonDivisor(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width);
    string str = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / nGCD, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / nGCD);
    MessageBox.Show(str);
}

static int GetGreatestCommonDivisor(int a, int b)
{
    return b == 0 ? a : GetGreatestCommonDivisor(b, a % b);
}
```

Comment: As I thought, There is no library function. Thanks for an answer anyway ;)

Comment: My screen resolution is 1813x1024 and am not sure why it returned "1024:1813" ?

Comment: My Screen resolution is 1366* 768 but it return 384:683 ! what can i do

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a library function to do it, but that code looks good.  Very similar to the answer in this related post of doing the same thing in Javascript:  [Javascript Aspect Ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186414/whats-the-algorithm-to-calculate-aspect-ratio-i-need-an-output-like-43-169)

Comment: -1: I would disagree with the `thought` that this is not possible.