# c++ Greatest Common Divisor

Tags: c++, algorithm, do-while, modulus

I am very new to C++ and am attempting create a function to implement the Euclidean algorithm that returns the greatest common divisor for two integer inputs.

The current approach I am taking keeps crashing - can you help me understand why?

```
int main() {    
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    cin >>  a;
    cin >> b;

    do {
        if ( a > b ) a = a % b;
        else if ( a < b ) b = b % a;
        else if ( a == b ) break;
    } while ( ( a || b ) != 0 ); 

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
while ( ( a || b ) != 0 );
```

this is wrong. It should be

```
while ( a != 0 && b != 0 );
```

On a side note, the Euclid's algorithm can be concisely implemented recursively:

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
   return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a%b);
}
```

Comment: http://www.nullptr.me/2012/01/07/c-template-metaprogramming/ there are a couple of GCD implementations. also recursive.

Answer (score 3):

Your term `( a || b ) != 0` will not resolve as you expect.
What you want to do is `(a != 0) && (b != 0)`
Or as `Cheers and hth. - Alf` suggests just `a && b`.

Comment: why not just `a && b`

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf This might be less readable/understandable for new C++ learners.

Comment: @abforce you're right i don't get `a && b` can you explain?

Comment: @DavidLoughnane `a && b` is evaluated to `true` when both `a` and `b` have non-zero values.

Answer (score 1):

Your while condition is wrong. You cant simplify it like that.

```
while ( ( a || b ) != 0 );
```

It should look like this.

```
while ( ( a != 0 ) && ( b != 0 ) );
```

By the way, you could make an much easier approach. Something like this

```
int main() {

int a, b, r;

cin >> a;
cin >> b;

while ( b != 0) {
    r = a % b;
    a = b;
    b = r;
}

cout << "The GCD is " << a << endl;

}
```

And there is another way, it doesnt requiere code the algorithm. Just use the libstdc++ algorithm library. [Libstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20664174/4655749)

Comment: made the same program... you also could have written while (b) instead of while (b !=0). But either way.. very cool use of the Euclidian algorithm!

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a closer look at your codes, maybe you are curious what does `while ( ( a || b ) != 0 )` do?

We now should evaluate `( a || b ) != 0`. In C/C++ evaluation begins from right to left, but `()` has more priority, so at run-time we would have:

```
bool r1 = a || b;  // intermediate result
bool r2 = r1 != 0;
while(r2);
```

Steps:

- `a || b` is evaluated to `true` when either `a` or `b` have non-zero value.
- `r1` will be casted to integer

  - `true` becomes `1`
  - `false` becomes `0`
- `r1 != 0` is evaluated and results an boolean value (`true` or `false`)
- `while` decides whether it should loop or not.