# GCD function syntax in C++

Tags: c++, greatest-common-divisor

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. I have a problem in writing GCD code and I can't find out any mistake. The errors are "identifier not found", and "gcd is unidentified". Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << __gcd(12, 40); 
}
```

Comment: Well, I would begin by including `numeric` just to make sure it is included... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/numeric (`gcd` is in the `numeric` standard header) then getting rid of the underscores might help...

Comment: What led you to believe that Visual C++ has a function named `__gcd`?

Comment: In situations like this, you can trust that the compiler is smarter than you.

Comment: What is `__gcd` and what made you believe that such function even exists?

Answer (score 2):

It's a hidden gem in `libstdc++` but **not** in MSVC. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20664174/5958455)

I am able to call this function on an Ubuntu 16.04 install as well as Windows Subsystem for Linux, but not Windows.

Note as well, there's a `std::gcd()` function available in C++17, in header `numeric`. See the same reference above.