# How can I find out if an aspect ratio is > 1:5?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, aspect-ratio

Say I'm targeting all images on a page and want to make sure that they all pass a test of being > 1:5...

This will give me the aspect ratio (from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186414/whats-the-algorithm-to-calculate-aspect-ratio-i-need-an-output-like-43-169)):

```
function gcd(a, b) {
    return (b == 0) ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}

var image = document.getElementById('image');
var w = image.width;
var h = image.height;
var r = gcd(w, h);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f8LwL/

But how can I make sure it's > 1:5 always?

Comment: Looks like you want to simplify the ratio. But you can just check `w/h > 1/5` as you can compare floating point numbers easily.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you're asking. You have a method to compute image dimension greatest common denominator, but ratio is x:y, and how do you propose to force image ratios on a site that's not yours?

Comment: How about dividing height by width and looking at the result. It should be 5 with very little or no remainder.

Comment: @pimvdb yeah that's going to work. Thanks.

Comment: @AK4749 I'm not forcing image ratios on a site that isn't mine. Not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: @bob_cobb bad interpretation of what you said, as you were!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why are you attempting to find gcd's? Your aspect ratio is your width to height ratio.. ie `w/h` .. so to ensure that your aspect ratio is > 1:5 (ie > .2), just check `(w/h) > (1/5)`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if(w/h > 1/5 ) {
    alert("Aspect ratio is fine");
} else {
    alert("Aspect ratio is too low");
}
```