# Calculate apsect ratio width based on height

Tags: javascript, css, math, fullscreen, aspect-ratio

I have an inline img that is 1280(w) x 1024(h) and is contained within a div. The divs dimensions are set 100%(w/h) of the viewport with overflow hidden.

I want to use the image as a fullscreen background and require that it fills the viewport completely regardless of dimensions with no borders showing. It must keep its aspect ratio and I would also like the image to be centered at all times. I am aware that to achieve this some of the image will be cropped.

I believe if make the image height match the viewport height and calculate the width based on the images aspect ratio this will work but I am unsure how to do this. Can anyone help?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186414/whats-the-algorithm-to-calculate-aspect-ratio-i-need-an-output-like-43-169

Comment: use `.naturalWidth` and `.naturalHeight` of `img` to calculate the original aspect ratio.

Comment: What's wrong with `background-size: cover;`?

Comment: @Hashem Thanks for the reply but as I said above its an inline img not a background-image

Answer (score 0):

Use backstretch http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

```
$("#demo").backstretch("http://urltoimage.jpg");'
```

set #demo to 100/100% width and height

Comment: thanks for the reply I would like to achieve this without using a plugin if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question but a potential alternative -- have you tried the `min-height`/`min-width` CSS properties?

HTML:

```
   <div class="container">
       <div class="image-wrapper">
           <img src="..." />
       </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { 
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: grey;
}

.image-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-wrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mkjoyep1/

In the example, `.container` (your full width/height div), fills the page width `vw/wh` and the `.image-wrapper` has its `width/height` set to `100%` which will match the parent's width and height. With `overflow: hidden` acting as the crop mechanism you can then stretch your image to fill it's container. I've positioned the image in the center with the method explored [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).

This appears to work for me on Chrome and Firefox.

*Edited to include html/css

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not 100% glued to using an img tag, you can do the following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#background {
  background: url('path/to/img.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```