# Finding a natural number fraction equal to a real number fraction

Tags: c++, algorithm, fractions

This is more like a math problem but i think here is the rights place to ask and it might be usefull to someone.

Here is what the problem is asking for:

> Given two real numbers (rA and rB) find the smallest two natural numbers (nA and nB) so that
>
> rA / rB = nA / nB

For those who did not understand properly, the problem is asking for an [Irreducible fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_fraction) that is equal to some given real number.

My problem arrives when it becomes a precision problem and it takes a lot of time to find those numbers (Ex: `rA = 665.32` and `rB = 875.1`) and i dont even know if there is such a combination of natural number to match the problem.

I also implemented a little `KeyPress` so that you can still check how much `nA` and `nB` got without making your console full.

The most efficient way i came up is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> // just for GetAsyncKeyState()

int main()
{
    /** The two natural numbers*/
    unsigned long long nA=1;
    unsigned long long nB=1;

    /** The two real numbers*/
    double rA;
    double rB;

    std::cin >> rA >> rB;

    bool bPairFound = false;

    /** The maximum of which nA or nB could go. */
    /** If the value is set to 0, the algorithm will stop when nA or nB overflows */
    #define NUMBER_LIMIT 0x0

    if ((double) nA / nB == rA / rB) bPairFound = true;

    while(bPairFound == false)
    {
        if ((double) nA / nB > rA / rB) nB++;
        if ((double) nA / nB < rA / rB) nA++;
        if ((double) nA / nB == rA / rB) bPairFound = true;

        /** A little keyPress that will show you how much nA and nB got. */
        /** Press space while the program is running. */
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x8000)
            std::cout << "nA: "<<nA<<"   nB: " << nB << "  ---> "<< (double) nA / nB << "   " << rA / rB << std::endl;

        if (nA <= NUMBER_LIMIT || nB <= NUMBER_LIMIT) break;
    }

    if (bPairFound == false) std::cout << "No pair could be found in the set limit." << std::endl;
    if (bPairFound == true) std::cout << "nA: "<<nA<<"   nB: " << nB << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**My questions are:**

1. Can i make this algorithm more efficient?
2. How can i set the `precision` of the comparrison to 6 digits?
3. Is there any way to determine from the start if there is such a pair inside `unsigned long long` range?

EDIT: Here are some more examples that take too much time to solve or are unsolvable.

`rA = 1426.33` `rB = 12.7`

`rA = 764342.33` `rB = 98.02001`

`rA = 1.0001` `rB = 1.010001`

Comment: Are your decimal points values fixed? Since the user has to manually types these values in, I would think so. If so, you could just eliminate the decimals to start and then reduce.  For example, for `rA = 1426.33 rB = 12.7`, you could multiply by 100 on both to get `142633` and `1270` respectively.  Then do standard reduction on `142633/1270` (which coincidentally, is the irreducible fraction).

Comment: Is the input of the algorithm supposed to be two numbers with a finite decimal representation, or two numbers with a finite binary representation? The code and examples seem inconsistent on this

Comment: @harold the two numbers taken at input have a finite decimal representation. (though i dont quite understand what do you need that for)

Comment: @HydraZerg that means you can write them as fractions already (integer divided by a power of ten) and then you have two fractions that you can divide and simplify. It also means that using `double` is a whole heap of trouble.

Comment: Now i see it. I can't believe i haven't seen this solution....

Comment: @selbie But still why doesen't my code see that combination as valid? I have just tested my code and it checks this combination, but seems to consider it `false`. Any idea why ?

Comment: @HydraZerg *Any idea why ?* -- Do not compare doubles for equality and expect them to be equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than precision issues<sup>(a)</sup>, you can do this most efficiently simply by ensuring the numbers are integers and then dividing them both by the greatest common divisor.

Specifically, pseudo-code such as:

```
tA = rA
tB = rB
while tA != int(tA) or tB != int(tB):
    tA = tA * 10
    tB = tB * 10
gcd = calcGcd(tA, tB)
nA = tA / gcd
nB = tB / gcd
```

GCD implementations should be fairly easy to find here on Stack Overflow.

In fact, here's [one I prepared earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186414/whats-the-algorithm-to-calculate-aspect-ratio-i-need-an-output-like-43-169/1186465#1186465) :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Precision issues can be solved by using an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library such as [MPIR](http://mpir.org/).

Comment: I believe that @paxdiablo answer might be more efficient.  I have not tried it myself, but it probably is better.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be more efficient.

```
while(bPairFound == false)
{
    double left=(double)nA*rB;
    double right=(double)nB*rA;

    if(left>right){
         double quotient=left/right;
         unsigned long long prevB=nB;
         nB*=quotient;
         if(prevB==nB){
              nB++;
         }
    }else if(right>left){
         int quotient=right/left;
         unsigned long long prevA=nA;
         nA*=quotient;
         if(prevA==nA){
              nA++;
         }
    }else{
         bPairFound = true;
    }
    /** A little keyPress that will show you how much nA and nB got. */
    /** Press space while the program is running. */
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x8000)
        std::cout << "nA: "<<nA<<"   nB: " << nB << "  ---> "<< (double) nA / nB << "   " << rA / rB << std::endl;

    if (nA <= NUMBER_LIMIT || nB <= NUMBER_LIMIT) break;
}
```

Since you are increasing the number by the quotient, you will skip quite a few steps in the early process.
Also this implementation has more multiplications and less divisions. Since multiplication takes a lower toll, this method will be more efficient.

I hope this helps.

edit 1:
I found a way to add precision to the system

```
double left=(double)nA*rB;
double right=(double)nB*rA;
double quotient=left/right;
unsigned long long test;
if(quotient>=1){
   test=quotient*1000000;
}else{
   test=100000/quotient;
}
if(test==1000000){
    bPairFound = true;
}else if(left>right){
    unsigned long long prevB=nB;
    nB*=quotient;
    if(prevB==nB){
        nB++;
    }
}else if(right>left){
    unsigned long long prevA=nA;
    nA*=1/quotient;
    if(prevA==nA){
        nA++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This still suffers from having to rely on two doubles being exactly equal.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: You do have a point. I didn't think of that. But this implementation does get to the solution faster than the previous one.
While coming to a solution, I ended up just focusing on the first question.