# UV rect calculation came unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

explain this numbers please 9/3*4 =12 ? what these number?

```
and how this will convert form 4:3 to 16:9 ?
```

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like this would rather belong on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and has nothing to do with coding especially not with Unity3d

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186422/7111561

Comment: `(16/9) / (4/3) * 9 = 12`

Comment: It works because that's what math does. 9, divided by 3, times 4, is 12. Just like 2 plus 2 is 4 and not 5.

Comment: hello smart, Just I am asking about how this 9 / 3*4 will end with this (16/9) / (4/3) * 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 4:3 the width/height ratio is 1.33 but in 16:9  it's 1.77 (16/9)  so in the 16:9 ratio you increase the width of the window and you will need more tiles.

I hope this makes more sense to you :

```
9    1.33

x    1.77  

x = 1.77*9/1.33 = 12
```

Comment: @periva  4/3 *4/3 = 16/9(or 1.33*1.33=1.77) .So You just need to multiply your ratio by 4/3 to get ratio in 16/9 and in your case :  9/3*4 = 9*(4/3)